# MariaDB 10.4.13 on Fedora 31

Tags: fedora, log-files, mariadb

Learning MariaDB on Fedora 31. Installed successfully, able to connect; however, cannot seem to get the error log global variables to register.

Steps taken:

1. Created maria.log file in `/var/log/`
2. Added
   `[mysqlid]  log-error = /var/log/maria.log`
   to `/etc/my.cnf`
3. Restarted mariadb service.
4. Changed permission based on "How to view mariadb log?" thread on this forum.

When I query `show global variables like 'log_error';` I still get empty value. Nothing is written to the file.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: That was it. OMG! Have been on this for the whole afternoon! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your section heading is misspelled:

```
[mysqlid]
```

It should instead read as:

```
[mysqld]
```